# Apply mutate across different columns according to name pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tibble.

```
> merged_data 
# A tibble: 168,747 × 15
   person_id      tmax_3 tmax_2 tmax_1 tmax0 tmax1 tmax2 tmax3 tmin_3 tmin_2 tmin_1 tmin0 tmin1 tmin2
   <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 2 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 3 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 4 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 5 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 6 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 7 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 8 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
 9 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
10 0101500002010…   21.6   21.0   21.3  22.0  22.6  20.0  22.4   11.7   11.2   11.6  14.0  11.2  12.4
# ℹ 168,737 more rows
# ℹ 1 more variable: tmin3 <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The tmax0 column corresponds to the max temperature on the day person i was surveyed. For example, tmax_3 corresponds to the max temperature three days before, tmax3 corresponds to the max temperature three days after. tmin stands for minimum temperature.

I would like to calculate the average temperature for each day as the average between the max the min temperature with efficient. Let's say what if I had 100 days before and 100 days after.

In other words, I would like to get this same result but with less code.

```
merged_data <- merged_data %>%
  mutate(tavg_3 = (tmax_3 + tmin_3) / 2,
         tavg_2 = (tmax_2 + tmin_2) / 2,
         tavg_1 = (tmax_1 + tmin_1) / 2,
         tavg0 = (tmax0 + tmin0) / 2,
         tavg1 = (tmax1 + tmin1) / 2,
         tavg2 = (tmax2 + tmin2) / 2,
         tavg3 = (tmax3 + tmin3) / 2)
```

ChatGPT recommended using:

```
tavg_2018 <- merged_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("tmax"), list(avg = ~ (. + get(paste0("tmin_", cur_column()))) / 2)))
```

However, this didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Alonso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `paste0` use `gsub` to replace `tmax` by `tmin`. Additionally, I use the `.names` argument of `across` and `rename_with` to rename the average columns. Finally note that there is no need for `rowwise()`.

Using some fake example data:

```r
merged_data <- data.frame(
  person_id = 1:5,
  tmax_1 = 1:5,
  tmax_2 = 1:5,
  tmin_1 = 1:5,
  tmin_2 = 1:5
)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

merged_data %>%
  mutate(across(
    starts_with("tmax"),
    list(tavg = ~ (. + get(gsub("tmax", "tmin", cur_column()))) / 2),
    .names = "{.fn}{.col}"
  )) |> 
  rename_with(~ gsub("tmax", "", .x), starts_with("tavg"))
#>   person_id tmax_1 tmax_2 tmin_1 tmin_2 tavg_1 tavg_2
#> 1         1      1      1      1      1      1      1
#> 2         2      2      2      2      2      2      2
#> 3         3      3      3      3      3      3      3
#> 4         4      4      4      4      4      4      4
#> 5         5      5      5      5      5      5      5
```